# How can I sent an activation link to my registered user in Laravel?

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I'm trying to sent an **activation link** to my registered user.

---

Here is my `postRegister()` function

```
public function postRegister(){

    $validator = Validator::make( Input::all(), array(
      'name'           => 'required|min:2|max:20',
      'email'          =>'required|max:50|email|unique:users',
      'username'       =>'required|max:20|min:3|unique:users',
      ));

    if ($validator->fails()) {
      return Redirect::to('/')
      ->with('error_register','Something Wrong')
      ->withErrors($validator)
      ->withInput();
    }



    $user = new User;
    $user->name = Input::get('name');
    $user->username = Input::get('username');
    $user->email = Input::get('email');
    $user->code = str_random(60);
    $user->password = '';
    $user->active = 0;
    $user->type = 'Aveniros';

    $user->save();



    // Email
    Mail::send('emails.activation', array(

      'username'=>$user->username,
      'name'=>$user->name,
      'code'=>$user->code,
      'email'=>$user->email

      ),
    function($message){

      $message->from(env('MAIL_USERNAME'),'Aveniros Site');
      $message->to( $user->email, $user->name )->subject(' Aveniros Site Activation ');

    });

    return Redirect::to('/')
    ->with('success',' Your Account has been created ! <small> Email has been sent to set-password, and activation.</small>');
  }
}
```

---

## Bug

`$message->to( $user->email, $user->name )->subject(' Aveniros Site Activation ');`

---

## Error

> **Undefined variable: user**

[image]

---

How can I use/call my `$user` variable ?

I thought we can access them after the `$user->save();` - right ?
But clearly, I can't. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my own answer, I just realize that I need to add `use ($user)`

into this line `function($message) use ($user){`

---

## Final Mail::Sent() should look like this

```
// Email
Mail::send('emails.activation', array(

  'username'=>$user->username,
  'name'=>$user->name,
  'code'=>$user->code,
  'email'=>$user->email

  ),
function($message) use ($user){

  $message->from(env('MAIL_USERNAME'),'Aveniros Site');
  $message->to( $user->email, $user->name )->subject(' Aveniros Site Activation ');

});
```